# React Native styling issue. Invariant violation

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

In **react native** I am stying component with below style

```
const style = StyleSheet.create({
    height: 100,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "rgb(201, 204, 204)"
})
```

But it gives error:

[image]

It seems that `borderBottomColor` is a valid property. I can't find out the reason for error.

If add style directly.  i.e., without `StyleSheet.create` then everything runs perfectly and style also get applied

```
const style = {
    height: 100,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "rgb(201, 204, 204)"
}
```

Is it recommended to use styles directly in react native?

Comment: What is the element that this is being applied to? Not all of them can have borders

Comment: @Kai It is View, style applies if I use without `StyleSheet.create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `StyleSheet.create` isn't quite right.  Try:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    foo : {
        height: 100,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: "rgb(201, 204, 204)"
    }

})
```

Then reference it as `styles.foo`, as in:

```
<View style={styles.foo} />
```

You can also combine both stylesheet and inline styles like so:

```
<View style={[styles.foo,{backgroundColor:'green'}]}/>
```

Finally, the stylesheet can have multiple named styles like:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    foo : {
        height: 100,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: "rgb(201, 204, 204)"
    },
    bar : {
        width:50
    }

})
```

Comment: Okay, it worked but can you explain a little more about `Stylesheet.create`. What it does exactly rather than returning the same object which has passed to it?

Comment: I haven't dug too much into it, but it just returns an id when using `styles.foo` instead of the actual object (which you can get using `Stylesheet.flatten(styles.foo)`).  Presumably this is more efficient.